# Objective-C @property use of macro parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

question:

I create a class for ARC and No-ARC, but in ARC, use strong, in No-ARC, use retain; So

my code:

```
    #if __has_feature(objc_arc)
    #define PARAMETER  strong
    #else
    #define PARAMETER  retain
    #endif
    @property (PARAMETER) NSString *myName;
```

is that right? thanks very much!

Comment: Why you created that? Are you sure property will be always strong/retain?\

Comment: You can use `strong` under non-ARC too.

Comment: You can also use `retain` under ARC ^^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I see no reason for doing this. You can use `strong` in a non-ARC environment too.

Answer (score 1):

`strong` works in ARC and non-ARC, the only thing you have to avoid when ARC is enabled is using `autorelease`, `release` and `dealloc` so this code is unnecessary.

Comment: in Non-ARC，I release @property （strong）NSString *myName; or just self.myName = nil. is that right?  Thanks very much!